# How to get the contacts from iPhone on Laravel

Tags: php, ios, laravel

Is there any library or reference where I can import the contacts from iPhone?
Can it be done via PHP or Laravel?

The scenario can be when user opening the website on iphone safari. 
Thanks

The similar plugin to import contacts from Google:
https://github.com/srajbr/OpenInviter (no support anymore)
http://codecanyon.net/item/invitee-advance-invite-system-for-crea8social-/12236680

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can import contacts directly from the device through the browser, only if you developed a native app.

The library you provided can import contacts from the Google **account** but not from any device.
You can, however, use a user's iCloud account and make CardDAV requests using [christian-putzke/CardDAV-PHP](https://github.com/christian-putzke/CardDAV-PHP) <sup>(GitHub)</sup>, for example.